# Error en laravel al hacer una migración con Mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

verán, en las ultimas semanas he estado aprendiendo Laravel en una distro de Linux(Manjaro). Mientras trataba de hacer una migracion con Laravel me surgió el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según estuve investigando recientemente, el error se debe a un driver o a una ext que al parecer no esta instalado en la version de mi Php; sin embargo, este no es mi caso ya que revise mi php.ini y el la ext si esta  habilitada. Existe alguna manera de arreglar este error ? Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

SS de mi archivo .ini

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Evidencia de que el archi PDO esta activo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos sobre el SO que uso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos sobre la DB que uso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿podrías agregar la línea de tu php.ini donde se verifique que tienes descomentada dicha línea?, además ¿qué sistema operativo usas?

Comment: ¿Que versión de Mysql estás utilizando? ¿Es mariadb o mysql? ¿Está bien configurado en tu archivo `config/database.php` ? Es raro que estos errores aparezcan en un so Linux, ya que suele venir bastante bien preparado para estas cosas.

Comment: Hola @EdgarBorrásCarcelén, acabó de editar mi pregunta con lo que me preguntaste; además, mi archivo config/database.php si esta bien configurado.

Comment: En linux las extensiones que tenés que habilitar son las que terminan en `.so` no las que teminan en `.dll`, como la que tenés de pgsql. Y lo que mostrás del phpinfo es sólo para web, tenés que habilitarla para cli si querés usar php en línea de comandos.

Comment: Hola, cómo puedes ver en mi PHP.ini no tengo nada relacionado con pdo_mysql, qué debo hacer ? Buscar el archivo .so de la extensión PDO y pegarlo en la carpeta ? O simplemente añadir la línea extension pdo_mysql.so ?

Comment: Si está en el directorio predeterminado, puede ser qu no tenga la extensión .so. Buscá todo lo que diga mysql.

Comment: Uso manjaro tambíen y está así `extension=pdo_mysql`

Comment: Hola, agregué la ext .so en mu carpeta de Php y sigue sin funcionar. Será que desinstalo Xampp e instalo WampServer el error se seguirá presentando ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que usas php-cli para correr artisan y el php de XAMP para la aplicación. El php-cli no tiene el driver que necesitas.

Yo correría un `sudo apt install php-mysql` para afianzar que tienes el driver instalado correctamente.

No uses xamp, usa docker o el servidor web de php o artisan.

Comment: Hola, aquí en Manjaro cambían un poco las cosas, el comando sería    pacman -S php-mysql; sin embargo una vez ejecuto el comando obtengo el siguiente error error: target not found: php-mysql

Comment: Cierto, intenta php-imap o php-pdo..debe existir algún equivalente. Lo que buscas es el driver de mysql o para Arch Linux.